# Can't burn CDs/DVDs

Tags: 11.10, brasero, k3b, burning

I own a Sony VAIO VPCEA35FL Laptop, and I'm having problems burning CDs/DVDs.
It seems that the burn process itself works, but once the disc is done, it can't be played.
I tried Brasero and k3b, both without success.
Sometimes the TOC can be read without a problem, but the data never is readable.
Also, when I try to play video DVDs, the dvd drive becomes noisier and usually the video stops for a few seconds.
This is a weird behavior, since a couple days ago I was using another O.S. and it worked just fine.

I *think* that this wasn't a problem using Natty.

What can I do?

Answer (score 2):

First, test your laptop's cd/drive. Insert some running(new is better) disk(cd and dvd) and ensure that it can read/run each disk successfully.

Second, Check disk speed in brasero/k3b before burn the disk. Set disk speed(Dvd : 8X and cd/mp3: 24X). Do not multi-task during burning. That means leave your laptop alone during burning process running.

Edited Version:

> I tried Brasero and k3b, both without success

What is the error message that brasero or k3b shows?

Again about burning process, after burn dvd brasero automatically eject the drive or shows a warning "Eject the cd drive manually". So if it will not automatically eject then just eject manually.(it is not a major task but should done).

If you can open your written dvd(i know data is not readable) then provide the output:

```
ls -l /media/cdrom0
```

What kind of output shows if you do this:

```
cp -a /media/cdrom0/anyfile anyfile
```

Comment: That's what I did.. I was about to take my PC to warranty, so I installed windows back, and then I tried to burn a CD, which burned perfectly.
I never burn discs at full speed, and those times I wasn't multitasking..

Comment: Sorry for the late response, I didn't know you edited the post..
Burning process ends correctly, but data isn't readable.
I inserted a bad-burned disk and it doesn't even get mounted. So /media/cdrom0 isn't available.

Comment: can you read other dvds (not burned by you) without any problem? Is this problem start after fresh install ubuntu?

Comment: I can read disks with Ubuntu. I noticed that playing a certain video DVD it cuts several times (like every 5 minutes), it buffers a bit and it starts playing again. I'm not quite sure if it was the disk itself or the drive. This happened on VLC, Totem and XBMC.

Comment: To solve your problem i need to know how did your problem start. Did you ever burn dvd successfully in ubuntu?. OR this problem start after install something or change in your system.?

Comment: I'm not quite sure, I don't burn disks a lot, but I remember burning disks successfully with Natty.
I should try to install a fresh Ubuntu on another partition, right?

Comment: your can install it in save partition.

Comment: Sorry for the extra-late response.. I had 3 fresh installs of ubuntu-based distros, among them: Ubuntu Oneiric, Linux Mint 12 and now 13. This problem persists. I been able to burn a couple disks by making the ISO image from Brasero, then burning it with cdrecord. But it eventually fails, too.. Here's a pastebin from the last log from brasero: http://pastebin.com/4A8Vm1qy

Comment: sometimes brasero fail but not frequently. Use k3b, it works great.

Answer (score 0):

it could be the back-end it uses which is probably cdrkit, you can read more about it [here](http://cdrtools.sourceforge.net/private/cdrecord.html)

you could replace it with a [ppa](https://launchpad.net/~brandonsnider/+archive/ubuntu/cdrtools)

Comment: You posted the same answer [elsewhere](https://askubuntu.com/a/1028327/250300). You should rather vote/flag to close as duplicate, or, if the question is not a duplicate, tailor the answer to this specific question. Note that posting the same link in many answers can be considered spamming.